# Objective-C graphics drawing speed

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking to draw to the screen, pixel by pixel. I've got this code working but its slow... I find this very very odd as the same kind of code written in javascript is super fast. fast enough that I has to slow down my interval that calling this...

What do I need to do to be able to speed this up by at least 2 or 3 times?

**objective-c**

```
- (void)drawPixelAtX:(int)X atY:(int)Y
{
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:NSMakeRect(X, self.frame.size.height - Y, 1, 1)];
}


- (void)drawCharater:(int)charCode atX:(int)charX atY:(int)charY color:(NSColor*)color;
{
    if (charCode >= [self.font count])
        return;

    [color set];
    NSArray *template = [self.font objectAtIndex:charCode];
    for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if ([[template objectAtIndex:y*8+x] intValue] == 1)
                [self drawPixelAtX:(charX * 8 + x) atY:(charY * 16 + y)+1];
        }
    }
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    for (int x=0; x < 80; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < 25; y++) {
            AnsiScreenChar *c = [self.screen objectAtIndex:(y*80)+x];
            [c.bgColor set];
            [NSBezierPath fillRect:NSMakeRect(x*8, self.frame.size.height - ((y+1)*16), 8, 16)];
            [self drawCharater:c.data atX:x atY:y color:c.fgColor];
        }
    }
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

**javascript**

```
function updateDisplay() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var data = $this.data('ansi');

    for (var i = 0, length1 = data.screen.length; i < length1; ++i) {
        var a = data.screen[i]; // cache object
        for (var j = 0, length2 = a.length; j < length2; ++j) {
            if (a[j][4]) {
                data.ctx.save();
                data.ctx.beginPath();
                data.ctx.rect(data.fontWidth * j, data.fontHeight * i, data.fontWidth, data.fontHeight);
                data.ctx.clip();

                data.ctx.fillStyle = a[j][0];
                data.ctx.fillRect(data.fontWidth * j, data.fontHeight * i, data.fontWidth, data.fontHeight);

                data.ctx.fillStyle = a[j][1];
                drawCharater.call(this, a[j][2], [j, i], 1);
                data.ctx.restore();

                a[j][4] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Profileing info**

```
Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
12371.0ms   21.8%   12371.0     objc_msgSend
2612.0ms    4.6%    2612.0      CFNumberGetValue
2446.0ms    4.3%    2446.0      _class_getInstanceSize
1910.0ms    3.3%    1910.0      -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]
1482.0ms    2.6%    1482.0      _CFExecutableLinkedOnOrAfter
1384.0ms    2.4%    1384.0      object_getIndexedIvars
1350.0ms    2.3%    1350.0      -[AnsiView drawCharater:atX:atY:color:]
1277.0ms    2.2%    1277.0      OSAtomicCompareAndSwap64Barrier$VARIANT$mp
1270.0ms    2.2%    1270.0      ripl_BltShape
1261.0ms    2.2%    1261.0      -[__NSCFNumber intValue]
1185.0ms    2.0%    1185.0      CFRelease
1047.0ms    1.8%    1047.0      CGSShmemGuardUnlock
1005.0ms    1.7%    1005.0      ripr_Rectangles
```

I take it CFNumberGetValue is dealing with the `intValue` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would do is profile your code, and see what takes so much time. My guess is that a lot of time is spent here:

```
[[template objectAtIndex:y*8+x] intValue]
```

If my guess is right, you should be able to gain some speed by switching template from `NSArray` to a regular C array of integers.

**EDIT**:

Now that I see the profile, I think my guess was right. Did you try switching to C arrays?

If you are open to a different approach to rendering fonts, see [this article](http://www.streamingcolour.com/blog/2009/08/27/texture-atlases-and-bitmap-fonts/) on texture atlases, it may give you some nice ideas.

Comment: this is a better article on doing texture atlases with calayer IMHO http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/

Comment: @slf It's funny how that article links to the one I posted (in fact, that's how I found my link).

Comment: This did speed things up a little but not enough. I'm going to try user57368's method. I'm marking this correct as its the only one that sped up the current algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Invoking the fillRect method of NSBezierPath to draw each and every pixel is crazy. If you must draw things a single pixel at a time, then draw into your own buffer, and when it's ready to display, *then* you send it into OS X's highly vector-oriented hardware-accelerated OpenGL-based graphics system. If you're not going to take advantage of any of the advanced drawing primitives offered by Quartz, then don't make a million calls to Quartz per frame. If you don't want to implement the blitting yourself, use SDL or Allegro. But you should really consider whether every letter needs to be drawn pixel-by-pixel. OS X's graphics system is very good at compositing images, as that is its primary purpose. And by the way, why can't you just use normal text-rendering methods and bundle in your own font file?

Comment: I've tried finding exact fonts, can can't. The fonts I have found, when displayed, get distorted and are not 100% pixel perfect. I would rather not deal with 3rd part libs at all for this. I originally was mucking with a NSBitmapImageRep and updating the data directly (not setPixel.) That was 100 times slower than this.

Comment: It's possible to get pixel-accurate font rendering in OS X. The Proggy fonts work just fine in Terminal and other apps. If you can't find a font that suits your needs, use FontForge.

Comment: @user57368 can you include an example or link on how to use/bundle custom fonts?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly agree that this method of drawing is insanity.  Chances are there is a better way to do this.  Toggling the individual pixels of a bitmap then calling a single bind texture and a single draw is the first thing that comes to mind.

Assuming you will not or can not change this algorithm, from your profiling info it looks like you are spending all your time sending messages. The first thing I would do to speed it up is pull it all into a single ugly monster method instead of breaking it out into three.  Yes it's ugly and stupid, but it would effectively illuminate all the message sends inside the loop and perform only the logic.

EDIT:

Drawing to a bitmap context without `objc_messageSend` ...

```
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext (int pixelsWide,
                            int pixelsHigh)
{
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);// 1
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);// 2
    bitmapData = calloc( bitmapByteCount );// 3
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        return NULL;
    }
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,// 4
                                    pixelsWide,
                                    pixelsHigh,
                                    8,      // bits per component
                                    bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    if (context== NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);// 5
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );// 6

    return context;// 7
}

void DrawMyStuff()
{
    CGRect myBoundingBox;// 1

    myBoundingBox = CGRectMake (0, 0, myWidth, myHeight);// 2
    myBitmapContext = MyCreateBitmapContext (400, 300);// 3
    // ********** Your drawing code here ********** // 4
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myBitmapContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);
    CGContextFillRect (myBitmapContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200 ));
    myImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (myBitmapContext);// 5
    CGContextDrawImage(myContext, myBoundingBox, myImage);// 6
    char *bitmapData = CGBitmapContextGetData(myBitmapContext); // 7
    CGContextRelease (myBitmapContext);// 8
    if (bitmapData) free(bitmapData); // 9
    CGImageRelease(myImage);
}
```

[explanation of what it's all doing in the Quartz2D guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-CJBHBFFE)

Comment: do you have an example URL or tutorial or something? I don't mind changing this to something better but like I said I tried messing with a NSBitmapImageRep an is was slower....

Comment: I'll try to find a good example of what I'm talking about, did you try merging them into one monolithic method without any improvement?